# Can git be configured in Jenkins on a per-job basis

Tags: maven, jenkins, github, npm

I have a Jenkins job running a multi-module maven build, which uses the frontend maven plugin to build an AngularJS module. The module uses npm to pull in the project dependencies from github, but fails with the following error

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Error while executing:
[ERROR] npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git
[ERROR] npm ERR! 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] npm ERR! 
[ERROR] npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I've run the same command - `git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git` - locally which gives the same error, but making the following change to my .gitconfig allows it to complete successfully

```
[url "https://"]   
    insteadOf = ssh://
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

I've tried adding this to a file in the build, and setting the `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable in Jenkins to `${WORKSPACE}/config` but the error persists

Can git be configured in Jenkins on a per-job basis, or is there a maven or npm setting to configure git to use https instead of git or ssh ?